# $watch in an array to avoid duplicates

Tags: angularjs, duplicates, watch

I have a form where with ngmodel I do an array,
I want to watch ngmodel (array) to avoid that between input text would have duplicates
[image]

this would be an input

```
<md-input-container md-theme="default" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="padding:0; margin-top: 0;">
            <label>chairs</label>
            <input
            type="text"
            name="chairs"
            id="chairs"
            ng-model="data.home.chairs"
            required
            changeinput
            ng-maxlength="10"
            ng-minlength="10"
            maxlength="10"
            md-maxlength="10"
            ng-pattern="/^[2]{0,1}[m|M]{0,1}[2]{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,7}$/"
            />
            <div ng-messages="formExample.chairs.$error" ng-if="formExample.chairs.$dirty" md-auto-hide="false">
              <div ng-message="required && !valid">Required 2M26123200</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
```

this wolud be the watch
,$scope.data will be bounded to ngmodel

```
$scope.data = {};

        $scope.$watch('data', function (newValue, oldValue) {
          // check duplicates in ngmodel
        }, true);
```

but I dont know in deep how to use $watch to this case

Comment: `found.indexOf(currency.value)` **found** meaning???

Comment: sorry, is an array
var found = []

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the necessary code. Please take a look at [mcve]. Also, please explain what you expect this `$watch` to do. Please take a look at [ask].